# UI Interaction via HMD in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Currently, we are developing VR functions using MetaQuest 2 and Oculus Integration sdk. We developed tasks such as object retention, throwing, UI interaction, and finally tried to develop the ability to interact with the UI in a situation where only HMD exists, but unfortunately we couldn't find any information. Can I use Oculus Quest 2 and CameraRig of Oculus Integration to achieve the function I want?

While watching a YouTube video created 10 months ago, HMD tried to interact with the UI through raycast.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.